# how to append data on top of another using react js

Tags: html, reactjs

generally the data in react append below the data which is already appended but here I want to append data on top of appended data.

here is the code:

```
const inputData = document.getElementById("input-box").value;
const appendData = () => {

}
return(
<>
<input id="input-box" />
<button onClick={appendData}>append</button>
<div id="append-data">
<h1>{inputData}</h1>
<hr></hr>
</div>
</>
)
```

actually I want to append that append-data div on button click. but I want it to append the new append-data div on the top of that already existing append data div.

Comment: Is this as trivial as `inputData = inputData + document.getElementById("input-box").value`, or am I misunderstanding something in the question that would make it more complicated?

Comment: please tell me by editing the above code

Comment: The line of code I suggested would be the entire contents of your `appendData` function.

Comment: do you mean the appendData function would be "const appendData = () => {
inputData = inputData + document.getElementById("input-box").value
}"